# WP8.1 C# Windows Phone 8.1 Background Task WriteableBitmap Thread Error

Tags: c#, writeablebitmap, background-task, microsoft-band

I am trying to update the band Me Tile image from a background task and i get the following error at WriteableBitmap:

```
System.Exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap..ctor(Int32 pixelWidth, Int32 pixelHeight)
   at BackgroundTaskCS.UpdateBandTask.<LoadImage>d__f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
```

It looks like the WriteableBitmap needs to run on the UI Thread but I don't think I have access to UI thread since I need to update the tile without the app being open. Is there an alternative solution to this?

Below is the task I am using. Thanks in advance.

I started this question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8bccb52-d336-43d2-bb90-f1dd06d7cd94/wp81c-windows-phone-81-background-task-writeablebitmap-thread-error?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required) and was directed to stackoverflow because of the band.

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

             await UpdateMeTile();
            Debug.WriteLine("CS Task Run");

            _deferral.Complete();
        }

        private static async Task UpdateMeTile()
        {

            /// <summary>
            /// Connect to Microsoft Band and change the wallpaper.
            /// </summary>

            try
            {
                // Get the list of Microsoft Bands paired to the phone.
                IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
                if (pairedBands.Length < 1)
                {
                    return;
                }

                // Connect to Microsoft Band.
                using (IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]))
                {
                    // Change the wallpaper.
                    await bandClient.PersonalizationManager.SetMeTileImageAsync(await LoadImage("ms-appx:///Assets/SampleMeTileImage.jpg"));

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //this.textBlock.Text = ex.ToString();
                Debug.WriteLine("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Exception. {0}", ex);
            }

        }


        private static async Task<BandImage> LoadImage(string uri)
        {
            StorageFile imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(uri));

            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
            {

                WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
                await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
                bitmap.ToBandImage();
                return bitmap.ToBandImage();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Rob Caplan in the original MSDN forum post, be sure to derive your background task from [XamlRenderingBackgroundTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx).  Doing so will ensure that your background task's OnRun() method will be called on a "UI thread" (for the purposes of using UI-related types such as WriteableBitmap).