# UWP - How to use WriteableBimap in a background task? Alternative?

Tags: c#, opencv, uwp, background-task, writeablebitmap

The following code reads an image, and centers (cuts and copies) that image into a resulting image with  a black frame, returns the new image.

**Can i do it without using a writeablebitmap class?**

```
private async Task<WriteableBitmap> FrameToCenter(StorageFile image, Size newSize)
    {
        WriteableBitmap result = new WriteableBitmap((int) newSize.Width,(int) newSize.Height);

        WriteableBitmap bitmapToFrame = await StorageFileToSoftwareBitmap(image);

        Rect sourceRect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmapToFrame.PixelWidth, bitmapToFrame.PixelHeight);
        int a = (int) Math.Min(newSize.Height, newSize.Width);
        Rect destRect = new Rect((int) ((_screenResolution.Width - _screenResolution.Height)/2), 0, a, a);

        result.Blit(destRect, bitmapToFrame, sourceRect);

        return result;
    }
```

Everything worked fine, but then I tried to put that code into a BackgroundTask in UWP, that results in an exception due to the fact that I can not use WriteableBitmap on a different thread then the UI thread.

Is there anything else I can do? I need to run it in a backgroundtask though.

As well the line:

```
result.Blit(destRect, bitmapToFrame, sourceRect);
```

is actually using a WriteableBitmapEx extension which I won't be able to use. Any other way? I really dont see a way how to manipulate a bitmap on a background task thread. I am quiet lost here. I've been even thinking about using openCV library and just do it in C++, would that solve the problem?

There is as well [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180583/wp8-1-c-sharp-windows-phone-8-1-background-task-writeablebitmap-thread-error?rq=1), which mentions I should derive my background task from  [XamlRenderingBackgroundTask class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the XamlBackgroundTask the same way you would a regular BackgroundTask

```
public sealed class MyBackgroundTask : XamlRenderingBackgroundTask
{
    protected override async void OnRun(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        //your code here
        deferral.Complete();
    }
 }
```

The difference is that this will have access to the UI thread so you can use your WriteableBitmap.

I would just keep an eye on the important recommendation in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx) article.

> Important  To keep the memory footprint of the background task as low as possible, this task should be implemented in a C++ Windows Runtime Component for Windows Phone. The memory footprint will be higher if written in C# and will cause out of memory exceptions on low-memory devices which will terminate the background task. For more information on memory constraints, see Support your app with background tasks.

Comment: How can i inherit if my task is a sealed class? I dont get it.

Comment: you don't inherit from *your* task. Your task inherits from XamlBackgroundRenderingTask